# Probablity, rolling a dice 10 times

Tags: probability

Rolling a dice for 10 times, what is the probability of getting side with number 4, for 3 times?

To my knowledge I have to use Binomial distribution to solve the problem how ever I am not sure if the answer is just $P(x=3)$ or $P(x=0)+P(x=1)+P(x=2)+P(x=3)$? I am confused($n=10,p=1/6$).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is indeed P(X=3) = binompdf(n,p,k) = binompdf(10,1/6,3).